# Serving a antiquated ASP.NET web service on a NancyFX built site

Tags: asp.net, nancy

I'm dealing with some closed legacy code that uses the old ASP.NET asmx web services.

What I'd like to do is include the assembly, and then just inherit the class that makes up the web service on my own site. From there I'd just hit the end point like the old days (MyService.asmx?methodName=...) except I'm not sure how I can get NancyFX to ignore this route.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the instruction for [adding Nancy to existing site](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Hosting-Nancy-with-asp.net#adding-nancy-to-an-existing-site) and [using the fact that  directives in web.config are followed top to bottom, and the last one wins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa903367%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), something along the lines should help:

```
<handlers>
      <add name="Nancy" verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="*"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" type="System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandlerFactory, System.Web.Services" validate="false">
</handlers>
```

Comment: I think you also need to ignore the route that the services are under but thanks!

Comment: I did that using 
 <location path="handlers">
  <system.webServer>
   <handlers>
    <remove name="Nancy" />
   </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
 </location>